# C++: flat initializer list for nested struct?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

Having defined

```
struct A {
  int a,b;
};

struct B {
  A a;
  int b;
};
```

the following initializations are obvious:

```
B b1 = { { 1 } };    // initializes b1.a.a
B b2 = { { 1, 2 } }; // initializes b1.a.a, b1.a.b
B b3 = { { 1 }, 2 }; // initializes b1.a.a, b1.b
```

But I am suprised that VC++ 2013 also allows these initializations without any warning:

```
B b4 = { 1 };       // initializes b4.a.a
B b5 = { 1, 2 };    // initializes b5.a.a, b5.a.b
B b6 = { 1, 2, 3 }; // initializes b6.a.a, b6.a.b, b6.b
```

Are flat initializer lists for nested structures/classes standard C++?

Comment: FYI: in all your examples, all the elements are initialized.  The ones you haven't specified are initialized to 0.

Comment: Yes this came from C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is standard C++. In aggregate initialization (and *only* in aggregate initialization, not in other forms of list-initialization), braces can be elided, effectively flattening the containment hierarchy of an aggregate.

Comment: thanks for giving the relevant keywords (aggregate initialization, brace elision). http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization does not make it easy to understand 'brace elision' for a newbie concerning this concept.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a standard *C++* which is described in the *8.5 Initializers*.

It's called a *brace elision* and can be applied in the case of aggregate initialization.

From the *n4296*, *8.5.1.12 Aggregates*:

> Braces can be elided in an initializer-list as follows. If the
>   initializer-list begins with a left brace, then the succeeding
>   comma-separated list of initializer-clauses initializes the members of
>   a subaggregate; it is erroneous for there to be more
>   initializer-clauses than members. If, however, the initializer-list
>   for a subaggregate does not begin with a left brace, then only
>   enough initializer-clauses from the list are taken to initialize the
>   members of the subaggregate; any remaining initializer-clauses are
>   left to initialize the next member of the aggregate of which the
>   current subaggregate is a member.

Here is another example from the *8.5.1.13*:

```
struct A {
    int i;
    operator int();
};

struct B {
    A a1, a2;
    int z;
};

A a;
B b = { 4, a, a };
```

In this example *a1* is initialized with *4*, *a2* is initialized with *a* and *z* is initialized with the result of *operator int()* for *a*.

Comment: wow, the given example is involved. On the one hand I feel like "Hats off to the compiler implementers", on the other hand I wonder whether this complexity is really necessary, given the difficulties to understand such code.

Comment: @coproc I just hope I'll never see such code snippets in the production code I will be working with :)

Comment: MISRA C rule 9.2 seems to discourage brace elision, but the google c++ coding guidelines do not mention brace elision. An oversight?